# string comparison if & else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, string-comparison

I am trying to compare strings in the array. I don't know why the strings are always never equal.

```js
var person = ["Sam", "John", "Mary", "Liz"];
var firstName = prompt("enter name");
var message = "";

for (x in person) {

  var firstName = person[x];

  if (firstName === x){ 
    message = "Found Person";
  } else {
    message = "Nothing compares!";
  }
}

console.log(message);
```

Comment: Did you `break;` the loop ?

Comment: your loop will hold the value for last Liz as for loop will execute for all rather use indexOf

Comment: `Array#indexOf` would be easier option :)

Comment: `x` is index. And inside `for` `firstName` is overridden. Use `if (firstName === person[x])`. Use `for()` instead of `for...in` to iterate over array.

Comment: This code is very confused. You have two variables called `firstName`, and you are comparing an array element against an array index. You may want to try explaining your program [to a rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: To add to the answers already here. You use the variables `x` and `firstName` to determine your match. You don't appear to understand what these values are and how they are changing over time. Add `console.log(x, firstName)` below your `for` statement to see the values as your program executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var people = ["Sam", "John", "Mary", "Liz"];

var firstName = prompt("enter name");

var personFound = people.some(dude => dude === firstName);
var message = personFound ? "Found Person" : "Nothing compares!";

console.log(message);
```

This basically checks if `some` (even one) `dude` in the `people` array satisfies the condition of `dude === firstName`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 
    var firstName = person[x];

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/moguveracu/1/edit?js,console)

```
for (var x in person) {

//   var firstName = person[x];

if (firstName == person[x])
  {

      message = "Found Person";
      break;
  }

else 
  {
      message = "Not Found";
  }

//console.log(firstName);

} 

console.log(message);
```

Comment: hi, it does not find Liz or anyone

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. just remove break; from else part

Comment: thanks, it works. I see my mistakes. This was great help, this solves in the simplest manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = ["Sam", "John", "Mary", "Liz"];
var firstName = prompt("enter name");
var message;
for (var x in person) {

  console.log(firstName);
  console.log(person[x])
  if (firstName === person[x])
    {
      message = "Found Person";
    }
  else 
    {
      message = "Not Found";
    }
console.log(message);
}
```

Best Way to found string available in array or not

```
console.log(person.includes(firstName));//it's return true false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This..

```
var person = ["Sam", "John", "Mary", "Liz"];
var firstName = prompt("enter name");
var message = "";

$.each(person,function(index,name){
    if (firstName.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
      message = "Found Person";
      return false; 
    }
    else
    {
      message = "Nothing compares!";
    }       
});

console.log(message);
```

its working, tested before posting..

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some part of your code, hope it works for you now.

```
var person = ["Sam", "John", "Mary", "Liz"];

var firstName = prompt("enter name");

var message = "";

for (x in person) {

//    var firstName = person[x];

        if (x.localeCompare(firstName)) {

        message = "Nothing compares!";
    } else
        {

        message = "Found Person";

    }

}

console.log(message);
```